# Need a RegExp to find character not surrounded by plus signs

Tags: javascript, regex, error-handling

Can somebody please help? I need to sort through a string to check for any single character from a-z that is **NOT** surrounded by plus signs on both sides specifically Please help?

So for example then, I will get strings that are at least 1 char long which will be like:

`Input = "+d+=3=+s+" (returns "true"--all chars are wrapped in pluses)`,

or `Input = "f++d+ (returns "false"--the 'f' is not bordered.)`

From the above I want to return a true or false value myself, so I'll be using the regex.test(str) function to do so.

re: examples of what I've tried so far-> `/\b*\w\b*/g;, /[^+]|\=\w[^+]|\=\/g;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since JavaScript doesn't have look-behind, rather than just a straight `regex.text(str)`, I think you may need something *very slightly* more complicated.

If you remove all of the characters surrounded by `+`, then if there are any left in the result, you want a `false` result and if there are not you want `true`. So:

```
if (!/[a-z]/.test(str.replace(/\+[a-z](?:\+[a-z])*\+/g, ""))) {
    // All characters surrounded by `+` (or there were none to start with)
} else {
    // Some unbounded
}
```

That expression is a bit complicated, so:

- `\+` - A literal `+` (the first one of a series)
- `[a-z]` - Followed by a character a-z
- `(?:\+[a-z])*` - Followed by zero or more occurrences of a literal `+` and a character a-z
- `\+` - A literal `+` (the final ending one of a series)

That's to handle `+b+` as well as `+b+b+b+b+`.

That'll give a false positive for a string that doesn't have any a-z characters in it to start with, so if that's a possibility, check for that in advance, e.g.:

```
if (!/[a-z]/.test(str)) {
    // String has no a-z characters at all
} else if (!/[a-z]/.test(str.replace(/\+[a-z](?:\+[a-z])*\+/g, ""))) {
    // Has a-z characters, all of them surrounded by `+`
} else {
    // Has a-z characters, at least one not surrounded by `+`
}
```

Comment: Thank you. How would you handle strings like `"+b+b+"`? It seems to return `"+b"`, and gives a false negative result accordingly.

Comment: @user3698316: *"How would you handle strings like `"+b+b+"`?"* Um...poorly... :-| Hmmm....

Comment: Nvm. It seems I've fixed it: eg. `var input = (!/[a-z]/.test(str.replace(/\+[a-z]\+[a-z]?\+?/g, "")));`

Comment: Is there some way to improve on that? I feel like there definitely is.

Comment: @user3698316: Unfortunately, that only works for `"+b+b+"` and not for `"+b+b+b+"`. But you're on the right track, one sec.

Comment: @user3698316: `!/[a-z]/.test(str.replace(/\+[a-z](?:\+[a-z])*\+/g, ""))`, I believe.

Comment: Final attempt: (!/[a-z]/.test(str.replace(/\+[a-z]\+[a-z\+]*/g, "")));

Comment: Mine was posted just after yours: Sorry, and thanks!

Comment: @user3698316: Note the non-capturing group (`(?:\+[a-z])*`) in mine, your final attempt will give a false `true` for `"+a+a"`. And no worries, sorry for missing that out the first time.